# spinner load animation not going away after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

Im testing out this simple loading animation while the page loads, after the page should be displayed or in this case, a video. Problem is that the animation keeps on going forever despite the page/ video already being loaded . The video is being embed via youtube.
Here is the code

note : Youtube video ID is an example, it does not lead anywhere but the video does load

HTML

```
<div class = "loadelement"><span class = "spinner"> </span></div> 
   <iframe width = "100%" height = "530"
   src = "https://youtube.com/embed/EXAMPLE" title="Youtube video player "
    frameborder = "0" allow = "accelerometer; autoplay ; clipboard-write ; encrypted-media ; gyroscope ; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

CSS

```
.loadelement {
position : absolute ; top : 0 ; left : 0 ; 
height: 100vh ; width: 100%;
background: #fff ; display : flex ; 
align-items : center ; justify-content : center ; 


}

.spinner {

width : 80px ; height : 80px ; 
border : 8px solid #f3f3f3 ; 
border-radius : 50% ; 
border-top : 8px solid #01101a ;
animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
0% {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    transform : rotate(360deg);
}
```

}

Javascript

```
let loaderel = document.querySelector(".loadelement");
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
loaderel.style.display = "None";
});
```

Been trying to figure out the problem myself, any help would be greatly great. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It is possible to create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: sure, do you need the actual video link? would that be fine ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work. But you can try to add the `onload` attribute to your `iframe` to hide the loader when `iframe` is loaded.

*PS. I also change the selector to ID and added an id to you loader element, because it could be that you have a multiple loader on your page.*

```js
function hideLoader() {
  const loaderel = document.querySelector("#loader");
  loaderel.style.display = "none";
}

/*
* Below also works if you don't want the iframe onload attribute
*

const loaderel = document.querySelector("#loader");
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  loaderel.style.display = "none";
});

*
*/
```

```css
.loadelement {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.spinner {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid #01101a;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="loader" class="loadelement"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/K4TOrB7at0Y" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen onload="hideLoader()"></iframe>
```